# how do i declare a static property/name declared in xaml? or

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, static, non-static

I get this error,

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SilverlightForum.MainPage.stackPanelAssetsControl'   C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SilverlightForum\SilverlightForum\MainPage.xaml.cs  23  13  SilverlightForum
```

when using this xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelAssetsControl" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</StackPanel>
```

and the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs (code behind)

```
public static void AttachBoardControl()
{
    stackPanelAssetsControl.Children.Clear();
    stackPanelAssetsControl.Children.Add(SilverlightForum.App.forumBoardControl);
}
```

Can someone help me deal with this problem? how do i declare a static property/name declared in xaml? or is there a work around where i can deal with this error?

Thank you for all the help!!!

Comment: I would be careful of continuing down the path of having code for one control directly access UI elements in some other control.  This violates the design principle of separation of concerns.  Doing this leads to dark places that plague the nightmares of software maintenance engineers.  See if you can come up with a better way for the information to be communicated, such as using interfaces or events, that keeps the controls better insulated from one-another.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use instance level objects in static functions

Read here about [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: can you explain? or provide a url to understand better?

Answer (score 0):

Why is `AttachBoardControl` declared as `static`?

This is causing the error as you need an object to access `stackPanelAssetsControl`.

So either remove the `static` or you'll need:

```
public static void AttachBoardControl()
{
    pageInstance.stackPanelAssetsControl.Children.Clear();
    pageInstance.stackPanelAssetsControl.Children.Add(SilverlightForum.App.forumBoardControl);
}
```

Comment: because im accessing it from an other UserControl and it needs to be static

Comment: I am in MainPage how do i get the pageInstance? i tried this.stackPanelAssetsControl doesn't work

Comment: @Kathy - `this` won't work as you're not "in" the page. If you name the page you should be able to reference it through that.

Comment: i am writing all the code in MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs and there is an other usercontrol that has a button when clicked on that button in that usercontrol that usercontrol will add an other usercontrol SilverlightForum.App.forumBoardControl in the mainPage StackPanel

Comment: so how do i do this in a better way?

Comment: @Kathy - I think I'd have to see far more code than you can sensibly post in a Stack Overflow question, but take @Dan Bryant's advice.